# Apache `SetEnvIf` and duplicated headers

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, setenvif

We are using this kind of configuration to grant access to one of our sites

```
    <LocationMatch "/*">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)192\.168\." WhiteIP
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])\." WhiteIP
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)10\." WhiteIP
        Allow from env=WhiteIP
    </LocationMatch>
```

Indeed, there is another reverse proxy in front of this Apache server so all clients will have the header.

Problem is sometimes client have others proxies on their side and the `X-Forwarded-For` Header wil be either duplicated or concatenated. We handle the concatenation correctly with the `(,| |^)` regexp trick, but the problem is that Apache seems to run the `SetEnvIf` only against the first occurrence of the Header.

Documentation is unclear about this behavior. Any idea on how to handle this kind of case ? (note: we cannot control how our reverse proxy works, only Apache) Could that be qualified as a bug ? I couldn't find the right way to ask google about this and found no result. I've also tried digging into the mod_setenvif's code but that's out of my league.

**Precision** : CentOS 6, Apache 2.2.15 latest patch version

Comment: Note : this question was sent to users@httpd.apache.org mailing list too.

Answer (score 1):

If `SetEnvIf` sees regex-like characters in the first argument, it will go into a mode where it iterates over all headers that match the regex until there's a match.

You could use this by specifying `^X-Forwarded-For$` which would iterate over the multiple occurrences of this 1 header.

This is a workaround for the longstanding behavior of how many modules treat multiple occurrences.  This should be documented better as a module-specific solution.

Comment: i got the same answer from users@httpd.apache.org. i will test that ASAP indeed.
Thanks